# ¿Como importar un archivo csv en Cassandra?

Tags: python, csv, cassandra

Buenas tardes, intento importar un csv file en Cassandra que esta muy largo.
Esta tratando de los productos alimenticios: ingredientes, nutrición, etiquetas. Proviene de Open Food Facts. Enumera información sobre productos alimenticios: ingredientes, información nutricional, etiquetas, etc. La mayoría de los datos proviene de la información de crowdsourcing. El archivo [esta sobre de la plataforma abierta de datos públicos franceses data.gouv.fr](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/produits-alimentaires-ingredients-nutrition-labels/)

Intento el comando siguiente con todas las columnas que fue capaz de recopiar con un script python :

```
cqlsh> COPY bouffe(code, url, creator, created_t, created_datetime, last_modified_t, last_modified_datetime, product_name, generic_name, quantity, packaging, packaging_tags, brands, brands_tags, categories, categories_tags, categories_fr, origins, origins_tags, manufacturing_places, manufacturing_places_tags, labels, labels_tags, labels_fr, emb_codes, emb_codes_tags, first_packaging_code_geo, cities, cities_tags, purchase_places, stores, countries, countries_tags, countries_fr, ingredients_text, allergens, allergens_fr, traces, traces_tags, traces_fr, serving_size, no_nutriments, additives_n, additives, additives_tags, additives_fr, ingredients_from_palm_oil_n, ingredients_from_palm_oil, ingredients_from_palm_oil_tags, ingredients_that_may_be_from_palm_oil_n, ingredients_that_may_be_from_palm_oil, ingredients_that_may_be_from_palm_oil_tags, nutrition_grade_uk, nutrition_grade_fr, pnns_groups_1, pnns_groups_2, states, states_tags, states_fr, main_category, main_category_fr, image_url, image_small_url, energy_100g, energy-from-fat_100g, fat_100g, saturated-fat_100g, butyric-acid_100g, caproic-acid_100g, caprylic-acid_100g, capric-acid_100g, lauric-acid_100g, myristic-acid_100g, palmitic-acid_100g, stearic-acid_100g, arachidic-acid_100g, behenic-acid_100g, lignoceric-acid_100g, cerotic-acid_100g, montanic-acid_100g, melissic-acid_100g, monounsaturated-fat_100g, polyunsaturated-fat_100g, omega-3-fat_100g, alpha-linolenic-acid_100g, eicosapentaenoic-acid_100g, docosahexaenoic-acid_100g, omega-6-fat_100g, linoleic-acid_100g, arachidonic-acid_100g, gamma-linolenic-acid_100g, dihomo-gamma-linolenic-acid_100g, omega-9-fat_100g, oleic-acid_100g, elaidic-acid_100g, gondoic-acid_100g, mead-acid_100g, erucic-acid_100g, nervonic-acid_100g, trans-fat_100g, cholesterol_100g, carbohydrates_100g, sugars_100g, sucrose_100g, glucose_100g, fructose_100g, lactose_100g, maltose_100g, maltodextrins_100g, starch_100g, polyols_100g, fiber_100g, proteins_100g, casein_100g, serum-proteins_100g, nucleotides_100g, salt_100g, sodium_100g, alcohol_100g, vitamin-a_100g, beta-carotene_100g, vitamin-d_100g, vitamin-e_100g, vitamin-k_100g, vitamin-c_100g, vitamin-b1_100g, vitamin-b2_100g, vitamin-pp_100g, vitamin-b6_100g, vitamin-b9_100g, folates_100g, vitamin-b12_100g, biotin_100g, pantothenic-acid_100g, silica_100g, bicarbonate_100g, potassium_100g, chloride_100g, calcium_100g, phosphorus_100g, iron_100g, magnesium_100g, zinc_100g, copper_100g, manganese_100g, fluoride_100g, selenium_100g, chromium_100g, molybdenum_100g, iodine_100g, caffeine_100g, taurine_100g, ph_100g, fruits-vegetables-nuts_100g, fruits-vegetables-nuts-estimate_100g, collagen-meat-protein-ratio_100g, cocoa_100g, chlorophyl_100g, carbon-footprint_100g, nutrition-score-fr_100g, nutrition-score-uk_100g, glycemic-index_100g, water-hardness_100g) FROM 'bouffe.csv' WITH HEADER = true;
```

Pero no funciona

- hay columnas que no estan debajo de un encabezado de columna despues
  de `water-hardness_100g`:

[image: foto que proviene de librofiice que muestra que hay cosas despues de water-hardness_100g]

- Pienso que falta los tipos de las columnas.

Sería :

```
create ColumnFamily Bouffe
(Code varchar PRIMARY KEY,
url varchar,
...
)
```

Pero cómo hacer para 162 columnas mínimas sin contar aquellas que quizás no se deben tener en cuenta porque sin encabezado de columnas. Pensé en un script en Python pero tengo que hacerlo, obtendría los nombres de cada columna antes de pegarlos vartext. Para hacer esto:

```
CREATE TABLE emp(
   emp_id int PRIMARY KEY,
   emp_name text,
   emp_city text,
   emp_sal varint,
   emp_phone varint
   );
```

Como se muestra [en el ejemplo de tutorialspoint table creation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_create_table.htm).

Pueden ayudarme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era que era un archivo tsv con tabulacies para delimitadores.